# Combining face recognition with human pose estimation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, face-recognition

I want to create application that would be able to estimate human pose and recognize theirs face. The problem is, that each of these tasks, as far as I know, has to be executed by different kind of network, as I don't have suitable dataset or ability to write such network. 
In worst case, I'd have to use up 4 for different networks:
1) network to estimate human position, like this: https://github.com/michalfaber/keras_Realtime_Multi-Person_Pose_Estimation. Output of such network is, for instance, 19 points per detected person.

2) network for face detection to predict where on image are faces. I know I can make an educated guess using previously described points from human pose estimation, but I think it would be greatly imprecise. Example network: https://github.com/kpzhang93/MTCNN_face_detection_alignment

3) faces detected from point 2) would be fed into network that predicts face landing marks to obtain detailed position of faces. Example network: https://www.learnopencv.com/facemark-facial-landmark-detection-using-opencv/

4) Lastly, detected faces from point 2) would be fed into face recognition network like this one: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-perform-face-recognition-with-vggface2-convolutional-neural-network-in-keras/

Using these 4 network I imagine it working like this:

1) estimate human pose and get coordinates of heads

2) detect faces' bounding boxes

3) these bounding boxes are used to obtain detailed coordinates of faces landmarks. Using these landmarks coordinates I can find to which human pose estimations this face belongs.

4) Finally, having matched face and human pose estimation I can recognize this face and obtain their name.

My problem is, that are 4 different networks! assuming I'm lucky and each one of them takes just 1 second to run prediction, it might take 3-4 seconds to perform full analysis. 
Is there a better, quicker way except writing my own network (good luck) and training it on new dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea is good , it will be possible to resume all this in one network with many classes , but like you said it will be imprecise , as much as you separate the tasks as much as it becoms more precise , so i think it's better this way